# Ввод и преобразование файлов в zip

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, классы, zip

Недавно начал изучать классы и решил сделать проект, похожий из книжки "A byte of Python", но усовершенствованный. Я хочу создать проект, где пользователь вводит логин или почту и пароль:

```
class User:
""" Creating users for site """
def __init__(self):
    import os
    import time
    list_of_users = []
    target_dir = 'C:\\Backup'
    today = target_dir + os.sep + time.strftime('%Y%m%d')
    self.email_or_login = str(input("Your login or email: "))
    self.password = int(input("Your password(numbers only): "))
    list_of_users.append(str(self.password))
    if "@" in self.email_or_login:
        self.email = self.email_or_login
        list_of_users.append(self.email)
        target = today + os.sep + self.email + '.zip'
        print("Email:", self.email, "|", "Password:", self.password)
    else:
        self.login = self.email_or_login
        list_of_users.append(self.login)
        target = today + os.sep + self.login + '.zip'
        print("Login:", self.login, '|', "Password:", self.password)
    if not os.path.exists(today):
        os.mkdir(today)  # создание каталога
        print('Folder successfully created', today)
    zip_command = "zip -qr {0} {1}".format(target, ' '.join(list_of_users))
    if os.system(zip_command) == 0:
        print('Reserve cope successfully created in', target)
    else:
        print('Failed of creating reserve copy')
```

Компилятор выдаёт:

```
"D:\Мои программы Python\venv\Scripts\python.exe" "D:/Мои программы Python/Все мои программки/Классы/My_new2.py"
Your login or email: Maskito@gmail.com
Your password(numbers only): 2401
Email: Maskito@gmail.com | Password: 2401
zip error: Nothing to do! (try: zip -qr C:\Backup\20191023\Maskito@gmail.com.zip . -i 2401 Maskito@gmail.com)
Failed of creating reserve copy
```

С чем это связано я до сих пор не знаю

Comment: Проблема в том, что названия файлов или папок не поддерживают символ `@`. Но это я так, сказал, что первое в глаза бросилось. Может у вас еще проблемы есть

Comment: Код не очень выглядит, кстати

Comment: @МихаилМуратов, значит этот код вообще не приемлимый для реализации?

Comment: @МихаилМуратов, даже если я ввожу без собаки, то компилятор выдаёт ту же ошибку, значит проблема не в собаке

Answer (score 0, accepted):

а что именно вы архивируете?
Я внёс некоторые правки в ваш код, можете посмотреть ниже.

```
import zipfile
# Всегда лучше использовать готовый модуль, там уже решено большинство проблем
# и реализован основной функционал.


class User:
    """ Creating users for site """
    def __init__(self):
        import os
        import time
        list_of_users = []
        # я считаю, что лучше использовать относительные пути, если нет конкретной цели всегда
        # использовать конкретную директорию и есть проверка на её наличие.
        # указываем что рабочая директория та, где лежит исполняемый файл.
        target_dir = '.'
        # Для конкатенации путей есть метод os.path.join()
        today = os.path.join(target_dir, time.strftime('%Y%m%d'))
        self.email_or_login = str(input("Your login or email: "))
        self.password = int(input("Your password(numbers only): "))
        list_of_users.append(str(self.password))
        if "@" in self.email_or_login:
            self.email = self.email_or_login
            list_of_users.append(self.email)
            target = os.path.join(today, self.email + '.zip')
            print("Email:", self.email, "|", "Password:", self.password)
        else:
            self.login = self.email_or_login
            list_of_users.append(self.login)
            target = os.path.join(today,self.login + '.zip')
            print("Login:", self.login, '|', "Password:", self.password)
        if not os.path.exists(today):
            os.mkdir(today)  # создание каталога
            print('Folder successfully created', today)
        # zip_command = "zip -qr {0} {1}".format(target, ' '.join(list_of_users))
        # какой файл вы хотите заархивировать?

        # создаём файл для архива, или указываем существующий. Я создам для примера.
        with open('hello.txt', 'w+') as newFile:
            newFile.write('Hello world')
            newFile.close()

        # создаем экземпляр класса ZipFile, передаём ему путь где будет лежать архив,
        # указываем что будем в него писать, метод сжатия
        ziph = zipfile.ZipFile(target, 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
        # пишем в него файл, можно писать много файлов в цикле например.
        ziph.write('hello.txt')


        # Если в коде есть участок, который может вызвать исключение
        # можно обернуть его в try

        #if os.system(zip_command) == 0:
           # print('Reserve cope successfully created in', target)
        #else:
          #  print('Failed of creating reserve copy')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    User()
```